# O que significa byte*?

Tags: c#, .net, ponteiro

Estou estudando criptografia e peguei um exemplo em AES.

No código tem esse `byte*` e até mesmo `*variavel` e não consegui entender o que significa.

Este é o bloco que utiliza isto, citado acima:

```
 byte* byteArray = (byte*)unmanagedBytes.ToPointer();
 byte* pEnd = byteArray;
 while (*pEnd++ != 0) { }
 int length = (int)((pEnd - byteArray) - 1);
 secureStringBytes = new byte[length];
 for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
 {
      secureStringBytes[i] = *(byteArray + i);
 }
```

Este bloco está quase no final [deste link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`byte` não tem muito segredo é um tipo de dado que tem 1 byte e os valores possíveis dele vão de 0 à 255, é como se fosse um `int`, só que tem uma capacidade de representação menor de números diferentes.

O `*` aí não é multiplicação, isso é o que se chama de ponteiro, portanto quando você usa um `byte *` em uma variável está dizendo que o tipo desta variável é um **ponteiro para `byte`** e por isso ele é muito diferente do próprio `byte`, desta forma cria-se uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e assim acessa o dado em si, o byte, de forma indireta através dessa variável.

Neste caso específico é usado para fazer aritmética de ponteiros, então vai navegando por um conjunto de bytes um por um. Não é muito diferente de ter um `byte[]` (internamente esta forma usa aritmética de ponteiro, mas de uma forma específica), mas é uma forma muito mais simples e eficiente. Pode ver aquele operador de incremento, ele não está somando 1 no valor do byte e sim no endereço dele, ou seja, ele está indo para o próximo endereço disponível ali, como é um tipo `byte` ele vai para o próximo byte. Você pode ir somando ao endereço indefinidamente, pode até acessar algum byte indevidamente, o controle é seu, não é como código C# normal que há um controle, e este é o motivo de ser eficiente. Este caso dá para ver que é seguro sem ter que verificar em cada operação se está dentro da área do objeto.

Isto só é usado quando precisa de muita performance ou fazer algo que o jeito padrão do C# não permite, e note que isto só é possível em um contexto `unsafe` já que perde-se um pouco da segurança de acesso à memória. Não a toa foi usado em criptografia.

Este trecho mostra bem como é semelhante ao *array*:

```
*(byteArray + i)
```

Isto é exatamente o mesmo que fazer:

```
byteArray[i]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Pointer.cs).

Aquele código está pegando o endereço contido em `byteArray`, somando o valor de `i` e aí pegando o valor que está neste endereço (a tal da indireção), então o ponteiro (`*`) usado neste contexto é como se diz "acessar o valor contido neste endereço). O código do *array* mesmo tem verificações de segurança, por isso é mais lento.

Hoje C# tem formas diferentes de obter o mesmo resultado ([uma delas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0)), com mesma eficiência sem usar código `unsafe` e portanto ponteiros, mas nem todos cenários o ponteiro ainda é dispensável.

É extremamente raro precisar usar este tipo de coisa e quase todos programadores C# nunca usarão diretamente.

Answer (score 8):

Resposta curta: `*` significa ponteiro, ou seja `byte*` significa ponteiro para `byte`.
O uso de ponteiros significa, de forma rasa, que você vai lidar com a memória.

Para entender mais a fundo é só pegar algum conteúdo sobre ponteiros em C#, por exemplo:
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1659/usando-ponteiros-em-csharp.aspx